# Creating regexp with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating a query for mongodb:

```
app.get('content/:title',
function(req, res) {
  var regexp = new RegExp(req.params.title, 'i');

  db.find({
    "title": regexp,
  }).toArray(function(err, array) {
    res.send(array);
  });
});
```

But sometimes the title has a parenthese in it. This gives me the error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /cat(22/: Unterminated group
    at new RegExp (unknown source)
```

The title that is being searched for is cat(22).

What's the easiest way to make the regex accept parenthesis? Thanks.

Comment: You need to escape the parentheses in your pattern: i.e., `(` should be `\(`, otherwise the regex engine thinks it's an opening group character. There are a number of special characters you will need to escape: a quick Google found [this](http://simonwillison.net/2006/Jan/20/escape/#p-6), for example.

Comment: ...Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can escape all possible regex special characters with [code borrowed from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2593661/1106925).

```
new RegExp(req.params.title.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1"), "i");
```

Comment: I edited the regex to include the `|` character which means union in a regular expression body.  Anyone using the version without `|` might have subtle bugs.

Comment: @WayneConrad: If you mean `escape(...)`, then no, that's different.

Answer (score 1):

Escape it with a backslash. And test it on a site like http://rejex.heroku.com/

```
/cat\(22/
```