# Javascript Regex: create new a lookbehind regular expression with variable?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to create new a `RegExp` with variable by JavaScript. But I got trouble when I want to create new a `lookaround RegExp`:

```
var xvar = "_on";
var regex = new RegExp("(?<!" + xvar + ")(.gif|.jpg|.png)$");
#=> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<!_on)(.gif|.jpg|.png)$/: Invalid group
```

I tried to escape all special characters follow [Creating regexp with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882624/creating-regexp-with-special-characters), then it can create a new RegExp but just like a string, not a lookaround regex.

```
/\(\?<!_on\)\(\.gif\|\.jpg\|\.png\)\$/
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Javascript does not support lookbehind.

Comment: one way is to reverse the string... depends on what you are doing.

Comment: What's the ultimate goal?  Why can't you use a normal, non-capturing group, as in `"(?:" + xvar + ")(.gif|.jpg|.png)$"`?

Answer (score -2):

I don't know your goal of `RegExp` but quantifier `(...)` causes error in this situation. For example, use **non-capturing parentheses** `(?:...)`.

```
var regex = new RegExp("(?:<!" + xvar + ")(?:.gif|.jpg|.png)$");
```

Refer to: [Regular Expressions - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

@Alan Moore: you're right.

Comment: He's not trying to match `<!`, he's trying to use a negative lookbehind, which is not supported in JavaScript regexes.